# Reference book on the relation between modular forms and elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, textbook-recommendation

What is a modern reference book to understand the relation between modular forms and elliptic curves after the proof of the Taniyama–Shimura theorem?

Comment: Diamond-Shurman explains the relation very well. If you mean one specifically overviewing the proof of modularity conjecture, there is Manin-Panchishkin for instance, or Cornell-Silverman-Stevens.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.